# How can I come around a final variable?

Tags: android

I have a problem with reaching the variable `group_id`. When I have the code like this it says that group_id needs to be declared as final. It can't be final because I need to change the value in `try{...}` to the value from the response String and later use it in the `UserGroupRequest`.

If I press the auto fix in Android studio which changes group_id to a final int array the value of the variable in the try catch is right. However it doesnt stay right since it goes back to 0 since group_id is final. What I am meaning with this is that the program retrieves the id from the database without any problem.

Any suggestion how I can come around the variable being final?

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
final EditText etGroupName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGroupName);
    final Button bRegisterGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegisterGroup);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final int user_id = intent.getIntExtra("user_id", 0);
    final String firstname = intent.getStringExtra("firstname");
    final String lastname = intent.getStringExtra("lastname");
    final String mail = intent.getStringExtra("mail");
    int group_id = 0;




    bRegisterGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String groupname = etGroupName.getText().toString();


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        group_id = jsonResponse.getInt("group_id");



                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterGroupActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
                            intent.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
                            intent.putExtra("mail", mail);
                            RegisterGroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterGroupActivity.this);
                            builder1.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        etGroupName.setText("fel");
                    }
                }
            };


            RegisterGroupRequest registerGroupRequest = new RegisterGroupRequest(groupname,responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterGroupActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerGroupRequest);
           UserGroupRequest groupRequest = new UserGroupRequest(user_id, group_id, "admin", responseListener);
            queue.add(groupRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: you can define it as a global variable.

Comment: declare your group_id as class variable.

Comment: `final variable`... that's no **variable** at all! that's a **constant**!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare as `global variable` and then use it `anywhere` in class. You `dont have to make it final.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int group_id = 0; //Global Vaiable have access to whole class

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    // now use it anywhere in class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int group_id = 0; //Make It Public Global Variable
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

}
```

**Make It Public Global Variable**

Answer (score 0):

Please declare group_id as globalvariable. Then it is possible to change its value.

```
public class ClassName extends Activity{

    private int group_id ;
........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's happening due to try catch.
Make another variable in your success method and use as a group id and assign this value to your group_id value and you can also change your group_id any where,
Look at following,

```
public class C {
private int x;
public C() {
int x_val;
try {
  x_val = Integer.parseInt("someinput");
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  x_val = 42;
}
this.x = x_val;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will fix your issue:
You can do it like this

```
public class aclass {
  private final int myvar;
  public aclass() {
    int tmp_val;
    try {
      tmp_val = Integer.parseInt("12");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      tmp_val = 42;
    }
    this.myvar = x_val;
  }
}
```

Here is your code like above example:

```
    final EditText etGroupName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGroupName);
    final Button bRegisterGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegisterGroup);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final int user_id = intent.getIntExtra("user_id", 0);
    final String firstname = intent.getStringExtra("firstname");
    final String lastname = intent.getStringExtra("lastname");
    final String mail = intent.getStringExtra("mail");

    private final int group_id = 0; // declare your group_id as private final

    bRegisterGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String groupname = etGroupName.getText().toString();


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                   //TEMPORARY VARIABLE
                    int tmp_group_id;

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        tmp_group_id = jsonResponse.getInt("group_id");


                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterGroupActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
                            intent.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
                            intent.putExtra("mail", mail);
                            RegisterGroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterGroupActivity.this);
                            builder1.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        etGroupName.setText("fel");
                    }
                    this.group_id = tmp_group_id; // assign to actual variable
                }
            };


            RegisterGroupRequest registerGroupRequest = new RegisterGroupRequest(groupname,responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterGroupActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerGroupRequest);

           //also modify here make this.group_id
           UserGroupRequest groupRequest = new UserGroupRequest(user_id, this.group_id, "admin", responseListener);

            queue.add(groupRequest);
        }
    });
}

}
```